# Expected number of unique numbers after drawing $n$ balls from $N$ balls with $N$ different numbers $d$ times.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

## Problem:

We have $N$ balls and each of the balls are numbered $0,..., N-1$.

Each time, we draw $n$ balls from the set the numbers are recorded. The balls are then put back in.

Given $n<N/2$ what is the number of unique numbers after performing the drawing $d$ times?

## Example:

$N=6$, $n=2$, and $d=3$

draw $1$ : $[0,1]$ so I recorded $[0,1]$.

draw $2$ : $[0,1]$ because they are already recorded, I didn't record anything.

draw $3$ : $[0,5]$ I recorded $5$ because $0$ was already recorded.

In this example, after $d=3$,  I recorded 3 unique numbers $[0,1,5]$

Comment: Did you mean your question to be: “Determine the *expected number* of draws to choose half the numbers”?

Comment: Well *if one draws $d$ times, what is the probability of completes the half the numbers on the list.*

Comment: I’m going to take a guess as I’ve no real idea: something to do with the multinomial distribution?

Comment: My suggestion - put some numbers to it, work through it and then try and make a recurrence relation. Just on $d$, if $d \lt \frac{N}{2n}, \,$ it is not possible. If $d = \frac{N}{2n}, \,$ it is $\frac{N-n \choose n}{N \choose n} \times \frac{N-2n \choose n}{N \choose n} \times \frac{N-3n \choose n}{N \choose n}...\frac{N/2+n \choose n}{N \choose n}$.

Comment: @MathLover 

I think I should ask this differently.  I think *what is an expected number of unique numbers after drawing $d$ times*

Comment: First drawing, you get $n$ with certainty. Now after next drawing, the expected number of unique numbers $E(X) = n + 1.\frac{(N-n)n}{NCn} + 2.\frac{(N-n)C2.nC(n-2)}{NCn} + 3.... + n.\frac{(N-n)Cn}{NCn}$

Comment: Sorry for keep changing, I guess I don't need the solution but someone to consult to which is very hard when I'm working from home.
@MathLover Thank you, I will try to verify this.

Comment: @Tom that simply translates to expected number of unique balls after two draws as $2n - \frac{n^2}{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will calculate the expected number of unique numbers found after $d$ such draws.

Let $A_i$ be the event "the number $i$ was not drawn" for any $i \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$.

We have $\mathbb{P}(A_i)=\big(\frac{N-n}{N}\big)^d = \big(1-\frac{n}{N}\big)^d$.

Moreover, the number $X$ of unique numbers is just given by $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \chi_{A_i^c}$.

So $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E}[\chi_{A_i^c}] = N (1-\mathbb{P}(A_i)) = N\Big(1-\big(1-\frac{n}{N}\big)^d\Big)$.

Just a note: if we use $d=N$, and let $N \to +\infty$ (keeping $n$ constant), we get that the expected fraction $\mathbb{E}[X/N]$ goes to $1-e^{-n}$.

Comment: Something is wrong, in the last expression, if I want $\mathbb{E}[X/N]=0.5$, then $n=\log(0.5) ~ 0.3$, but that's against my intuition that n=1 is not optimal because as d->N, you get so many overlapping numbers

Comment: $n = -\log(0.5) = \log2$, anyway I don't understand what you mean. Can you please clarify? @Tom

Comment: Why would setting it equal to $0.5$ be optimal?

Comment: Actually, my bad. I think your solution is correct.